# How do I use VBA in MS Access to change the address of linked sharepoint lists

Tags: vba, sharepoint, ms-access-2013

At work we have MS Access databases that use sharepoint lists as linked tables because we like the stability.  The address of our sharepoint site is going to change.  I want to run a VBA sub to change the tables from the old address to the new.  Here is what I have so far, but there are two problems:

1. It does not automatically detect which tables are sharepoint lists without asking
2. Some tables are 'participating in one or more relationships' and give an error when deleted

How do I make it better?

```
  Sub ChangeSPTables()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim MBr As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim N As String

    Set db = CurrentDb
    For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
        If Not (tdf.Name Like "MSys*" Or tdf.Name Like "~*") Then
            N = tdf.Name
            MBr = MsgBox("Delete and relink " & N & "?", vbYesNoCancel)
            If MBr = vbYes Then
                DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, N
                DoCmd.TransferSharePointList acLinkSharePointList, "https://redacted", N
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Set tdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related tables can't be deleted but can be dropped.  Adding a table will also add related tables, so I was having troubles with duplicate adds.  I stored all names to delete first and re-add later (if they don't already exist).  The sharepoint address is part of the connection string so I was able to sift the tables I wanted like that.

Edit: Using the DoCmd.TransferSharePointList can cause lists with lookup columns to come in as read-only.  For lists like that, delete and add them manually after running.

```
Sub ChangeSPTables()
'Step through all table definitions and check if the old sharepoint address appears in the connection string
'If so, stores the name of the table, deletes all such tables, and re-adds them from the new sharepoint address
'The list is used because sometimes other tables are brought in automatically as relationships and I don't
'want extra copies or instances where the table has a 1 on the end of the name
'Will not work on things that have been renamed since they were brought in from sharepoint
'You should probably only run this on a copy of the database for saftey's sake

Dim db As dao.Database
Dim tdf As dao.TableDef
Dim MBr As VbMsgBoxResult
Dim i As Long: i = 1
Dim ListNames(1 To 20) As String 'Assumed to be 20 or less

'The old and new sharepoint addresses
Dim OldSP As String
Dim NewSP As String
OldSP = "https://old"
NewSP = "https://new"

Set db = CurrentDb
For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    If Not (tdf.Name Like "MSys*" Or tdf.Name Like "~*") And InStr(1, tdf.Connect, OldSP) > 0 Then
        ListNames(i) = tdf.Name
        i = i + 1
        Debug.Print tdf.Name 'For review of which tables were redone
        db.Execute "drop table [" & tdf.Name & "]", dbFailOnError 'drop table avoids problems with relationships between tables
    End If
Next

i = 1
Do Until ListNames(i) = ""
    If IsNull(DLookup("Name", "MSysObjects", "Name='" & ListNames(i) & "'")) Then 'Some things get re-added by relationship
        DoCmd.TransferSharePointList acLinkSharePointList, NewSP, ListNames(i)
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

'Hide the sharepoint tables
For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    If Not (tdf.Name Like "MSys*" Or tdf.Name Like "~*") And InStr(1, tdf.Connect, NewSP) > 0 Then
        Application.SetHiddenAttribute acTable, tdf.Name, True
    End If
Next

Set tdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```